# Perform selector for methods with arguments

Tags: swift, dylib

Consider the following class in dyLib

```
@objc public class MyClass : NSObject{
   
    @objc  public func printString(myStr: NSString)  {
           
            print("printString : \(myStr)")
        }
        
        @objc public func printAndReturn()-> String {
           
        let string = "Test String"
            print("On print and return \(string)  ")
            return string
        }
}
```

I am trying to call its method in the dyLib from another project like:

```
let value = instance1.perform(Selector("printAndReturn") ) //working fine 

instance1.perform(NSSelectorFromString("printString:"), with: "testString") or

instance1.perform(Selector(("printString:")), with: "testString" )
```

but crashing with error:

> printString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Please suggest the correct way to calling printString: method (methods with arguments) using perform selector.

Comment: `instance1.perform(#selector(MyClass.printString(myStr:)), with: "testString" )` should do the trick.

Comment: @Larme Since OP says `MyClass` is in a dylib, I don't think they are compiling against the library that declares `MyClass`, and so probably can't do that.

Comment: `instance1.perform(NSSelectorFromString("printStringWithMyStr:"), with: "testString")` then. The Swift method should be translated in Objective-C into `"printStringWithMyStr:`, not `"printString:"`.

Comment: @Larme Yeah I got that too. I was about to post that as an answer, but couldn't find where the Swift -> ObjC name translation rules are documented at all.

Comment: It's indeed somewhere, but I never know where. `With` being a common "introduction" keyword introducing a parameter. I used a project where I have Objective-C & Swift, to see the generated `MyProject-Swift.h` file and so the Objective-C methood declaration.

Comment: what is the difference printStringWithMyStr:  instance1.perform(NSSelectorFromString("printStringWithMyStr:"), with: "testString")
instance1.perform(NSSelectorFromString("printString:"), with: "testString").  both are same, right? only the function name changed

Comment: In Objective-C, `@objc  public func printString(myStr: NSString)` is `- (void)printStringWithMyStr:(NSString * _Nonnull)myStr;` `NSSelectorFromString` being "Objective-C" (note the quotes, since it's not completely true, but let's say it's more oriented Objective-C than Swift), it wouldn't surprise me to expect the Objective-C method only.

Comment: please note the method without arguments works find, the problem is with the methods with arguments.

Comment: Create a project with Swift & Objective-C, see the Project-Swift.h generate code. You'll see how the method are translated into Objective-C. But if there is no parameter, then, the method names should be the same. But that's not the case with parameters. Why? Objective-C is "wordy", "explicit". Using as seen "with" when in Swift, there is no "with".

Comment: Now I understand, it worked for me , Thank you Larme

Comment: I tried to print a NSPoint                                                                                         @objc  public func printpoint(myPt: NSPoint)  {
        print("point =  \(myPt.x)  , \(myPt.y)")
    }                                 instance1.perform(NSSelectorFromString("printpointWithMyPt:"), with: NSPoint(x: 10.5, y: 20.5))           Result : -     point  = nan(0x3ffffffffff00)  , 20.5.       point.x value is wrong and and point.y value is correct.